# Break Network between two hosts without pulling Cable

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, nic, internet

I have two Linux hosts HOST1 and HOST2 connected by cross cable.  How I can break the network between then without breaking the physical wire (I don't have access).

If i do:

`HOST1# ifconfig eth0 down`

Then NIC card will down. I just want to down link.  Is any other way we can make network link down?

Comment: What is the end goal here. Once the machines are separated do you still need access to them?

Comment: You say that they are connected by a cross cable, so I assume that it's a direct connection between the two hosts.  What is the problem with bringing the interface(s) down?

Answer (score 1):

If the cards are supported, you could probably use `mii-tool -F` or `ethtool` to force both ends into incompatible speeds.

Be sure to get the correct setting first so you can set them back to normal.

Comment: thanks for inputs, i am not sure how to set eth0 in incompatible speeds, Please provide the commands .

Comment: wouldn't this be equivalent to shutting down the interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a reject route in the routing table.

```
# route add -net X.X.X.X netmask 255.255.255.255 reject
```

If you want it persistent, you can add it to `rc.local` or something similar.

Comment: i was going to say the exact same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact outcome you want, you could implement subinterfaces and VLANs. This page has some configuration info: http://nixcraft.com/networking-firewalls-security/10447-linux-vlan-configuration.html

Comment: , Please provide the example in detail

Answer (score 0):

(install the iproute2 tool) and use this:

`ip link set eth0 down`

This will disable the link, bit keep the config.

Comment: "ip link set eth0 down" is equal to "ifconfig eth0 down"

Comment: You asked for "any other way we can make network link down?", which i answered...

Answer (score 0):

What's the current configuration?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Short of turning down NICs or pulling the cable, you could ensure those interfaces are in different IP networks (or remove IPs) so they can no longer communicate.